# What does a relation to the power of $-1$ mean? $R^{-1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Context: If relation $R$ is antisymmetric, then $R^{−1}$ is antisymmetric.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: $x R^{-1} y\iff y R x$

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relation $R^{-1}$ is the *inverse* [also called *converse*] of the relation $R$.

$(x,y) \in R^{-1}$ if and only if $(y,x) \in R$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation), it's called the *converse* relation

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks, added.